# Losses over frequency for microstrip vs. coplanar waveguide

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, transmission-line, microwave, skin-effect

At mmwave frequencies, coplanar waveguide transmission lines generally have lower loss than microstrip.  What accounts for this, besides radiated losses?  Or is the difference mostly related to the radiated losses?

Also, supposedly at microwave frequencies (C-Band and below), microstrip has lower losses than coplanar waveguide.  What explains this difference between behavior at microwave frequencies vs. mmwave frequencies? Is it primarily a radiated loss phenomena as well that accounts for this spectrum dependent difference?

I know that tightly gap coupled coplanar waveguide is less affected by surface roughness than microstrip.

Comment: Who claims this? I've never found the difference in my work to be substantial in simulation (and I've never taken the time to measure this in the lab... maybe I should)

Comment: See the following paper- [link](https://www.circuitinsight.com/pdf/insertion_loss_comparisons_pcb_constructions_ipc.pdf).  On page 4, you will find the following quote- "The losses of a CBCPW are usually worse at lower frequencies than a microstrip, however when designed correctly,the coplanar circuit will have nearly no radiation losses at high frequencies."  This isn't the only source on the subject I've encountered over time, bare in mind.  Rogers Corp in general has a number of articles on it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that never gets brought up in this discussion is plating. Coplanar lines will have higher concentration of current density around the sidewalls because the electric field terminates at the ground region on the same layer as the trace. Therefore, the plating also plays a role in contributing to total losses. This is one reason that RF/microwave transmission lines on a PCB use immersion silver instead of ENIG or another plating, it has lower losses at the relevant frequencies where you would want to use a coplanar arrangement. If you look at bare copper, there is basically no difference between microstrips and surface-layer coplanar waveguides.

Here's a great video showing measurements for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwNb0ndIT5k&t=135s

In this video, the spacing between the trace and the ground region on the same layer is very thin (clearly in violation of the 3W rule on a PCB). You can see that the total losses become significant once ENIG plating is added, amounting to an additional 0.5 dB/in. loss at 50 GHz.